# How do I prove that $\cos\left(2x\right)=1-2\sin^2\left(x\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry

While trying to solve the equation $\sin\left(x\right)=\cos\left(2x\right)$, a user on this forum suggested that I turn the equation into a quadratic form by converting $\cos(2x)$ using the identity $\cos\left(2x\right)=1-2\sin^2\left(x\right)$.

What is the logic behind this identity and how can I derive it?

Comment: What is your definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$?

Answer (score 6):

This identity follows from the more general

$$\cos (x+y)=\cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y$$

by $y=x$, that is

$$\cos (2x)=\cos (x+x)=\cos x \cos x - \sin x \sin x=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x=1-2\sin^2 x$$

using that $\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x$.

Refer also to the related

- [Proofs of $\cos(x+y) = \cos x\cos y - \sin x \sin y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/349435/505767)
- [How can I understand and prove the "sum and difference formulas" in trigonometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1292/505767)

Answer (score 4):

$$
\\\cos(2x)=\frac{(e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix})}{2}=1-2(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i})^2=1-2\sin^2{x}
$$

Comment: dont' forget the square the sine...

Answer (score 3):

Well, you'd first have to know the following identity.

$$\cos(a\pm b) = \cos a\cos b\mp \sin a\sin b$$

The diagram below demonstrates it perfectly.

[image: Valid XHTML]

From here, apply the general identity.

$$\cos(2a) = \cos(a+a) = \cos a\cos a-\sin a\sin a$$

$$\implies \color{blue}{\cos(2a) = \cos^2 a-\sin^2 a}$$

This can be rewritten by using $\color{purple}{\cos^2 a = 1-\sin^2 a}$ or $\color{purple}{\sin^2 a = 1-\cos^2 a}$.

$$\implies \cos(2a) = \cos^2 a-\color{purple}{(1-\cos^2 a)} = 2\cos^2 a-1$$

$$\implies \cos(2a) = \color{purple}{1-\sin^2 a}-\sin^2 a = 1-2\sin^2 a$$

Therefore, all three expressions are valid for $\cos(2a)$.

**Edit:** I am now aware that the diagram above is by Blue. You may want to check this link as well:

[How can I understand and prove the "sum and difference formulas" in trigonometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/how-can-i-understand-and-prove-the-sum-and-difference-formulas-in-trigonometry/1342#1342)

Comment: I'm flattered that you believe the diagram "demonstrates [the angle-sum relation] perfectly". In the future, I hope you'll be a bit more conscientious about citing [the source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342/409) and/or [the creator (in this case, me)](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/409/blue) of any content you "quote". (Far too many web communities circulate far too much uncredited content. Math.SE can do better.) Thanks!

Comment: I saw your “Trigonography” site and it had great stuff, but I wasn’t aware that this particular diagram was yours. :-) Sorry about that, I’ll definitely pay more attention from now onwards.

Comment: I appreciate it. :) BTW: If you didn't get the diagram from the answer I linked above, then where did you find it?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I was searching for diagrams for $\sin(a\pm b)$ and $\cos(a\pm b)$ while I was self-studying trig identities. But I didn’t really pay attention to the link. :-) It was one of the image results. (It certainly wasn’t MSE.)

Comment: Fair enough ... I should've started watermarking my images sooner. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Define $f(t)=\cos(2x-t)\cos(t)-\sin(2x-t)\sin(t)$.  We have $f'(t)=0$, hence $f$ is constant.  From $f(0)=f(x)$ follows $\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$.  Now use Pythagoras.

See also [Proofs of $\cos(x+y) = \cos x\cos y - \sin x \sin y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349435/proofs-of-cosxy-cos-x-cos-y-sin-x-sin-y/2996646#2996646), please.

Answer (score 2):

write $$\cos (2x)=\cos(x+x)$$
you know $$\cos(x+y)=\cos x\cdot \cos y-\sin x\cdot \sin y$$
So, $$\cos(2x)=\cos x\cdot \cos x-\sin x\cdot \sin x$$
Or, $$\cos(2x)=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$$
write $\cos^2x$ as $1-\sin^2x$

So, $$\cos(2x)=1-\sin^2x-\sin^2x$$

> you get$$\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2x$$

Similarly get $$\cos(2x)=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=1-2\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-1$$

Comment: Formatting tip:  Typing `$\sin x$`, `$\cos x$`, `$\tan x$`, `$\csc x$`, `$\sec x$`, `$\cot x$` produces $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, and $\cot x$, respectively.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes! thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I've formatted it for you.

Comment: @KM101 thanks !

Comment: @omega No problem!

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(2x)=\cos(x+x)=\cos(x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)\sin(x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$$
then we know that $cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$ so:
$$cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$$
you can find proof of the compound angle formula here:
https://www.math-only-math.com/proof-of-compound-angle-formula-sin-alpha-plus-beta.html