# Calculating $\ln(1+\sqrt3)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I distributed the natural logarithm and got $(0 + 0.549)$ [placing the values in a calculator].
However, the answer key states that the answer is $1.0051$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Four answers and so far I'm (I think?) the only one who's up-voted the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The logarithm is not linear.
That is, typically $\ln(x+y)\neq\ln(x)+\ln(y)$.

Comment: Not just "typically". $\ln(x) + \ln(y) = \ln(xy)$, so $\ln(x+y) \ne \ln(x)+\ln(y)$ unless $x+y=xy$.  For each  $y \ne 1$, there is exactly one real $x$ which makes $\ln(x+y)= \ln(x)+\ln(y)$.  For $0 < y < 1$ there is none.

Comment: Forgot I was dealing with logs where ln(a+b) can be contracted to ln(ab).

Comment: @Cetshwayo That's incorrect as well. $\ln a + \ln b = \ln ab$. But $\ln(a+b) \neq \ln a + \ln b$. You cannot simply distribute the log of a sum. However, the sum of logs (to the same base) can be expressed as the log of a product.

Answer (score 14):

### **You cannot distribute logarithms**

Answer (score 7):

You are confusing your identities. You are most likely confusing the identity $\ln(ab)=\ln a+\ln b$. In general $\ln(a+b)\neq\ln a+\ln b$. Also, note that if you are using a calculator, you do not need to simplify the expression; you can punch $\ln(1+\sqrt 3)$ straight into your calculator (but don't forget the brackets!).

Comment: It seems something of a leap to conclude that the identity that the original poster was thinking of was $\ln(ab)=\ln a+\ln b$.  More likely it was the false identity that says everything is linear. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you! The post has been edited to sound less certain :P

Answer (score 2):

As someone previously stated, logarithms are not linear. It can be confusing to keep the properties straight, but a good logic check is that if:

$$
\log(a+b) = \log(a)+\log(b)\\ \rightarrow \log(a)=\log(0+a)=\log(0)+\log(a)\space\space(a\neq0)\\\rightarrow \log(a)~ DNE ~~ \forall a
$$
Which is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the Taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$ at the point $x=1$. See [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291168/algorithms-for-solving-sqrt2).

Comment: That expansion is only valid for $|x|<1$.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood: You are right. I just noticed that. Corrected.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood: It is corrected.

Comment: I'm somewhat unhappy with the suggestion. You have to first calculate $\ln 2$ as the degree zero term of the Taylor series of $\ln(2+x)$ (which is what you are now suggesting). Then you need to substitute $x=\sqrt3-1$ to all the terms, so you also need to calculate $\sqrt3$ to a high precision.