# Taylor series for $\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm trying to figure Taylor series for $\sqrt{x}$. Unfortunately all web pages and books show examples for $\sqrt{x+1}$. Is there any particular reason no one shows Taylor series for exactly $\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: The Taylor series is only defined for smooth functions. The function $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. (Also, it is not defined for $x<0$.)

Comment: @copper.hat pitty! I really wanted to compare how similar the following expectations are $E[XY] = E[\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}]$ for centered r.v.s with variance 1. So perhaps I was hoping in the range -1,1 $XY \sim \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

*Short answer:* The Taylor series of $\sqrt x$ **at $x_0 = 0$** does not
exist because $\sqrt x$ is *not differentiable* at $0$.
For any $x_0 > 0$, the Taylor series of $\sqrt x$ at $x_0$ can be computed
using the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1 + u}$ at $u_0 = 0$.

---

*Long answer:* The [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of a function $f$
that is infinitely differentiable at a point $x_0$ is *defined* as

$$
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n = 
  f(x_0) + \frac{f'(x_0)}{1!}(x-x_0) + \frac{f''(x_0)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2 + \ldots \quad .
$$ 
Therefore:

- Asking for "the Taylor series of $f$" makes only sense if you specify
  the point $x_0$. (Often this point is implicitly assumed as $x_0 = 0$, in
  this case it is also called the [Maclaurin series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html) of $f$.)
- The Taylor series of $f$ at $x_0$ is only defined if $f$ is 
  infinitely differentiable at $x_0$. (But the Taylor series need 
  not be convergent for any $x \ne x_0$, and even if it converges in a 
  neighborhood of $x_0$, the limit can be different from the given function $f$.)

Each Taylor series is a [power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series)
$
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-x_0)^n 
$
and the connection is roughly the following: If there exists a power series
such that
$$
   f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-x_0)^n \text{ in a neighborhood of $x_0$}
$$
then

- $f$ is infinitely differentiable at $x_0$, and
- $a_n = {f^{(n)}(x_0)}/{n!}$ for all $n$, i.e. the power series is
  exactly the Taylor series.

---

*Now applying that to your question:* You are asking for the Taylor series of $f(x) = \sqrt{ x}$.
If you meant the Taylor series at $x_0 = 0$: It is not *defined* because 
$\sqrt {x}$ is not differentiable at $x_0 = 0$. For the same reason, there is
no power series which converges to $f$ in a neighborhood of $0$.

But $f(x) = \sqrt{ x}$ can be developed into a Taylor series at any $x_0 > 0$.
The general formula is given in
[Mhenni Benghorbal's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1106362/42969).
The reason that often only the Taylor series for $\sqrt{1 + x}$ is given
in the books is that – for the square-root function – the general case can easily be
reduced to the special case:
$$
   \sqrt {\mathstrut x} = \sqrt {\mathstrut x_0 + x - x_0} = \sqrt {\mathstrut x_0}\sqrt {1 + \frac {\mathstrut x-x_0}{x_0}}
$$
and now you can use the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+u}$ at $u_0 = 0$.

The same "trick" would work for functions like $g(x) = x^\alpha$ because
$g(x) = g(x_0) \cdot g(1 + \frac {x-x_0}{x_0})$

Comment: I wonder if I can use this "trick" for any function that is not differentiable at $x_0 = 0$? I could always find Taylor series for f(x+1), and then substitute $u = x+1$ to get back to original function f(x).

Comment: @bodacydo: No. Here we have used $f(x) = f(x_0) \cdot f(1 + \frac {x-x_0}{x_0})$  and that is not generally true for arbitrary functions. It also does not help to find the Taylor series of $f(x)$ at $x_0 = 0$ because using this would correspond to the Taylor series of $f(1 + u)$ at $u_0 = -1$ which does not exist.

Comment: pitty! I really wanted to compare how similar the following expectations are $E[XY] = E[\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}]$ for centered r.v.s with variance 1. So perhaps I was hoping in the range -1,1 $XY  \sim \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$.

Answer (score 27):

I assume you are talking about the Taylor series at $0$ for $\sqrt{x}$. Let's try to compute the Taylor series at $0$:
$$
f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)(x-0)+f''(0)\frac{(x-0)^2}2+\dots
$$
$f(0)=0$, but $f'(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}$ blows up at $x=0$. Since $\sqrt{x}$ doesn't have a first derivative at $0$, it doesn't have a Taylor series there.

Comment: pitty! I really wanted to compare how similar the following expectations are $E[XY] = E[\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}]$ for centered r.v.s with variance 1. So perhaps I was hoping in the range -1,1 $XY  \sim \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$.

Answer (score 12):

*Note: Strictly speaking, what is proved below is that $\sqrt{x}$ cannot have an asymptotic expansion of the form $a_0 + a_1 x + o(x)$ as $x \to 0$.*

There is no Taylor series for it at $0$. If there were, it would be
$$\sqrt{x} = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \dots.$$

Obviously, $a_0$ would have to be $0$, but $\sqrt{x}$ is much larger as $x \to 0$ than any expansion starting with $a_1 x$. For example, we'd have 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = a_1 + a_2 x + \dots \rightarrow a_1,$$
as $x \to 0$, but $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ doesn't have a finite limit as $x \to 0$.

On the other hand, it's easy to obtain the Taylor expansion for $\sqrt{x}$ at $a > 0$ from the one for $\sqrt{1 + x}$ at $0$. Setting $h = x - a$, you have
$$\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{a + h} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{1 + h/a},$$
and then you expand $\sqrt{1 + h/a}$ in powers of $h/a$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the definition  of a Taylor series does not require that it converges to the given function or converges at all.

Comment: In all honesty, I'm not really viewing it as a convergent series, but rather as an asymptotic expansion in powers of $x$. I concede that I used what is perhaps misleading notation (as a series), because the question seemed to be asking for intuition on the question. Despite the technical inaccuracy, the answer makes the essential point. Strictly speaking, what I have shown is that $\sqrt{x}$ doesn't have an asymptotic expansion of the form $a_0 + a_1 x + o(x)$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: pitty! I really wanted to compare how similar the following expectations are $E[XY] = E[\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}]$ for centered r.v.s with variance 1. So perhaps I was hoping in the range -1,1 $XY  \sim \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$.

Answer (score 8):

**The answer is correct.**

Note that you can find Taylor series of $\sqrt{x} $ at a point $a>0$ as

> $$ \sqrt{x} = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{\sqrt {\pi }}{2}\,{\frac {{a}^{\frac{1}{2}-n} \left( x-a\right)^{n}}{\Gamma\left( \frac{3}{2}-n \right)n! }}.$$

See my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291168/algorithms-for-solving-sqrt2).

Comment: So it can have a Taylor series but not a Maclaurin series?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, that's correct.

Comment: pitty! I really wanted to compare how similar the following expectations are $E[XY] = E[\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}]$ for centered r.v.s with variance 1. So perhaps I was hoping in the range -1,1 $XY  \sim \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$.

Answer (score 6):

if
$$
\sqrt{x}=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots
$$
then
$$
x=a_0^2+(a_0a_1+a_1a_0)x+(a_0a_2+a_1a_1+a_2a_0)x^2+\dots
$$
and if you want the identity theorem to hold this is impossible because $a_0=0$ would imply that the coeff of $x$ is zero

Answer (score 4):

Well, I know this is an old answered post, but referring to the question that all web pages and books doesn't show examples for $\sqrt{x}$,  on book, Thomas' Calculus Twelfth Edition on exercises of section 10.8, problem 9 the question is: find the Taylor polynomial of order 0,1,2, and 3 generated by $f$ at $a$ and the exercises are the following

[image: Thomas' Calculus exercises 10.8]

And the book also gives the answers, those are the following

[image: Thomas' Calculus answers to section 10.8]

I've posted the images of the book in order to show that at least there's one book with the worked exercise.

Internet is a very resourceful place, but good calculus books are a very good option to find lots of exercises and examples that have been worked by experts.

Comment: but in your book it is specifically stated that we look at taylor series at $a=4$, which is excluded in the OP's question. And exactly that is the problem. So I agree that calculus books are a good source for studying, but the above would not help the OP in a sense that he/she gains more insight in the matter.

Comment: Agree, but I was looking to give a more literal answer to the question asked by OP, showing that in fact there is one resource that has an example and not only examples for $\sqrt{x+1}$ are given. On the other hand, to give more insight, we could state: you could find the Taylor series generated by $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ at $x=a$ as long as $a>0$. But that was the answer given by @Martin R ^_^

Answer (score 3):

As in the other answers, $f:\mathbb{R}^+\bigcup\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}^+\bigcup\{0\};\,f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ has no derivative at $x=0$, so no Taylor expansion around $x=0$.

It's worth noting, however, that the signularity at $x=0$ is a different kind of singularity from the singularity $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\{0\};\,g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ that denies us a Taylor expansion for $g$ at $x=0$. This one is simpler to understand and is called a *pole*.

But your singularity is called a [*Branch Point*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point) and it is where two "branches" of a multi-valued function are joined in an essential way. Recall that $f_\pm(x)=\pm\sqrt{x}$ are both functions which are partial inverses to $x\mapsto x^2$. They "join" at $x=0$. Functions with branch points involving $n^{th}$ roots like yours can have a well-defined value at their branch points (unlike the pole example, which blows up to $\infty$ as one approaches the pole), but some derivative of the function fails to be defined at the branch point. For example, $x\to x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ is well defined at $x=0$, *and also* has a well defined derivative $x\to \frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ at $x=0$. But the second derivative is undefined there.

Answer (score 0):

Let  $u = x+1$. Then just substitute into that other Taylor Series. The reason it is found everywhere is simply because it is easy to calculate.

Comment: No, it does not exist.

Comment: @copper.hat Maclaurin series dne. Are you saying Taylor series dne for any $x_0 \in \ \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @bclc: No, it doesn't exist for $x_0=0$, it does exist for $x_0>0$.

Comment: @copper.hat You said 'it' dne. What is 'it' ?

Comment: @bclc: The Maclaurin series...

Comment: @copper.hat Bob said Taylor...?