# Expansion of a function of a GBM

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I'm a bit stuck on the following question: Suppose $X$ is a Geometric Brownian Motion with a drift $\mu$ and volatility $\sigma$. How can you expand, or approximate, the function $f(X)=(a + bX)^c$ in terms of powers of $X$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real numbers? Can anyone solve it?

Comment: Expand or approximate leaves a lot of room for interpretation. You should be able to "approximate" it by a Taylor polynomial of order $\lfloor c\rfloor\,.$

Comment: Thank you. That was my first attempt, but taking the expected value of f(X), which by linearity reduces to a sum including all the moments of X, I get that the result diverges. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Let's write the GBM as $$X_t=X_0e^{\sigma W_t+\mu t-\frac{\sigma^2 t}{2}}\,.$$ As we know the $n$-th moment of this is $$\mathbb E[X^n_t]=X_0^ne^{n\mu t+(n^2-n)\frac{\sigma^2 t}{2}}\,.$$ This does not diverge, and neither does a truncated Taylor expansion up to order $n=\lfloor c\rfloor\,.$ The fun probably starts when you want an infinite Taylor *series*. I have (lazy as I am) not worked on this since your question left room for interpretation. Where does this come from? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: That’s the expression for the n-th moment I am using. That diverges as n tends to $\infty$, even when dividing it by $n!$, such as for obtaining the expectation $E(e^{(X)})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}E(X^n)$

Comment: But what has $e^X$ to do with $f(X)=(a+bX)^c\,?$

Comment: I just wanted to point out that I don't understand the reason for these divergences, and to show that the same thing happens when applied to a function such as the exponential. Returning to the function of my original question, the expected value would be: $E[f(X)]= a^c \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
 \pmatrix{c \\n} b^{n}a^{-n}E[X^n]  = a^c \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
 \pmatrix{c \\n} b^{n}a^{-n} X_0^n  e^{n\mu t + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sigma^2 t}$ , and the n-th coefficient of this sum tends to infinity as n increases.

Comment: It is well-known that for a GBM $X$ the expectation $\mathbb E[e^X]$ is infinite. Not everything can be finite. If you are not just playing around you may want to let us know what the purpose of $f(X)=(a+bX)^c$ is and what your typical $c\,$s look like.

Comment: I was hoping to get or approximate the expectation of $\mathbb{E}[(a+bX)^c]$, where $c\in(0,1]$, so I asked for the expansion in terms of powers of $X$, since that was my first intuition. Any ideas?

Comment: It was highest time to mention what values that $c$ takes. I am getting tired of this question. Hint: study what the best way is to Taylor expand the [sqrt function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106344/taylor-series-for-sqrtx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use [Taylor's expansion with binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Binomial_series):

$$f(X)=a^c\left(1+\frac{b}{a}X\right)^c = a^c \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
 \left(\pmatrix{c \\n} b^{n}a^{-n}X^n  \right)$$
where
$$\pmatrix{c \\n}=\frac{c(c-1)...(c-n+1)}{n!}$$

Comment: Thank you. That was my first attempt, but taking the expected value of $f(X)$, which by linearity reduces to a sum including all the moments of $X$, I get that the result diverges. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @Eastwood94 I think the series must converges. Could you give me the expression of $\mathbb{E}(X^n)$ that you computed?

Comment: The expression I use is: $E[X^n]  = X_0^n  e^{n\mu t + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sigma^2 t}$

Comment: @Eastwood94 I thought $X$ followed the Brownian motion. But if $X$ follows the geometric brownian motion, the series does not converge. Indeed, *except* some specific values of $(a,b,c)$, $\mathbb{E}(f((a+bX)^c) = \infty$ in general.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification @NN2